# How to import 3 hourly data in daily basis into xarray for a whole year

Tags: python, import, netcdf, python-xarray

I was trying to import 3 hourly netCDF data into xarray and find its daily mean. I could do simply select particular day and get the daily mean, but how to do this process for a whole year? How to do this?

```
import xarray as xr

fname='/home/atmosphere/GRIDSAT-B1.2010.12.01.*.v02r01.nc'         
ds=xr.open_mfdataset(fname))
varlist=list(ds.variables)
imr=ds.sel(lat=slice(0,30),lon=slice(25,45)) #subsetting dataset
bt=imr['irwin_cdr']                          #making into a data array  
dailymean1=imrbt.mean('time')
```

in the above code I could get the daily mean for the 01 Dec 2010, but how can i find daily means for whole year? Your kind help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want to use a method called [`resample`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html):

```py
daily_mean = ds.resample(time='D').mean()
```

A major use-case for it is downsampling a timeseries to a regular coarser frequency (e.g. going from three-hourly data to daily mean data). Make sure that `ds` contains all the data you are looking to resample (you may need to alter your glob string).

Comment: Thanks. But if I write the code using resample

`fname='/home/atmosphere/GRIDSAT-B1.2010.12.01.*.v02r01.nc' `  
`ds=xr.open_mfdataset(fname))`
`bt=imr['irwin_cdr']`                         
`daily_mean = ds.resample(time='3H').mean()'`

Comment: Can you clarify please?

Comment: So how does it work? should I give like
`fname= /home/atmosphere/GRIDSAT-B1.2010.*.v02r01.nc' `
(asterisks on month) to get dailymeans for  whole year?

Comment: Exactly -- you can do multiple years (if you have more than one) at once too if you want.

Comment: And actually I had a typo in my answer -- you'll want to specify `time='D'` to resample to daily frequency.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helps. Btw one more doubt it saves into an array right?

Comment: Sure thing -- if `ds` is a Dataset, `daily_mean` will be a Dataset; if `ds` is a DataArray, `daily_mean` will be a DataArray.